Magento 2 skip quantity item validator when placing order
Stock quantity of the product in my cart is not sufficient. And when we validate the order we get the error "The requested qty is not available", how can I ensure that my order goes through even with the insufficient quantity. Could you help me, give me a clue to remove the stock validation when placing order.

You can enable backorder and disbale manage stock in above case. You can find config at Stores >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Product Stock Option >> manage Stock = No and backorders = Allow Qty Below 0

Thank you, that's right
